# Force keyboard to show up via button (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, uikeyboard

I have an UITextView and I don't want check editable option, how can call keyboard via a button?
This code doesn't work for me!

```
-(IBAction) yourButtonClick
{
    [myTextView becomeFirstResponder];
    [self.view addSubview:myTextView]; 
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the iPhone Application Programming Guide

> However, you can programmatically
>   display the keyboard for an editable
>   text view by calling that view’s
>   becomeFirstResponder method. Calling
>   this method makes the target view the
>   first responder and begins the editing
>   process just as if the user had tapped
>   on the view.

So to show the keyboard programmatically,

```
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

However, the keyboard will never show if the textView is not editable.

The purpose of showing the keyboard is to allow editing. I assume you just don't want the keyboard to appear when the user taps the text view. In this case, you can enable editable programmatically when the button is tapped.

```
-(IBAction) yourButtonClick
{
     myText.editable = YES;
     [myText becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

Then in the UITextViewDelegate, disable editable when the user finishes editing.

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
  textView.editable = NO;
}
```

Comment: ahaaaaa thank you very much i add this code textPad.editable = YES;
and works great

Comment: Hi Arrix, is there a way to programatically invoke Landscape soft keyboard in Portrait view ?