# Showing iOS onscreen keyboard without a TextField

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

I have a special iPad app where the onscreen keyboard must remain visible even if there is no UITextField being the first responder.

Supposedly, the keyboard appearing is controlled by UITextInputTraits.

So I've made my ViewController implement the UITextInputTraits protocol and added these methods to it:

```
- (UITextAutocapitalizationType) autocapitalizationType { return UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; }
- (UITextAutocorrectionType) autocorrectionType { return UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; }
- (UITextSpellCheckingType) spellCheckingType { return UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo; }
- (UIKeyboardAppearance) keyboardAppearance { return UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault; }
- (UIKeyboardType) keyboardType { return UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet; }
- (UIReturnKeyType) returnKeyType { return UIReturnKeyDefault; }
- (BOOL) enablesReturnKeyAutomatically { return NO; }
- (BOOL) secureTextEntry { return NO; }
```

Lastly, in the controller's `viewDidAppear` method I'm invoking `[self becomeFirstResponder]`

But that's apparently not enough to bring up the keyboard. What am I missing?

I do even get a call to my `keyboardAppearance` method, but the keyboard does not come up (or disappears when it was up) regardless.

I wonder if I have to implement another protocol, e.g. one for receiving input from the keyboard. Which one would that be?

Comment: Have you read this? Maybe it helps.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750445/force-keyboard-to-show-up-via-button-iphone-sdk][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750445/force-keyboard-to-show-up-via-button-iphone-sdk

Comment: Why don't you add an UITextView to the view outside the visible bounds (or hide it, or set it's alpha to 0), then call [textView becomeFirstResponder],

Comment: Yes, using a hidden Text field works in my special case. However, I'd still like to know how to write a custom edit field that doesn't rely on UITextField. I guess others might want an answer to that, too.

Comment: @Stefan A View Controller has no "editable" property, and when I add one to mine, returning YES, that doesn't make it work, either.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it's not enough to implement UITextInputTraits but one need to implement the UITextInput protocol so that one can react to typing on the keyboard.

After changing the implemented protocol in my view controller's interface declaration to `UITextInput`, and adding these properties, the keyboard appears - only for typing more methods neede to be implemented:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UITextRange *markedTextRange;
@property (readwrite, copy) UITextRange *selectedTextRange;
```

Answer (score 1):

A quicker solution to show the keyboard from your view controller, using `becomeFirstResponder` method, is to implement `UIKeyInput` protocol and return `YES` for `-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder` in your view controller. `UIKeyInput` protocol methods will be used in this case for handling keyboard actions.

Also be careful to return `YES` for `canBecomeFirstResponder` only when needed to avoid weird behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I am currently not able to check your suggestion. But if others should upvote and confirm yours, I'll give you the checkmark.